# Change direction of jquery slide menu from left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to change the direction of the slide from left to right only when clicking on "main menu link". I like the direction how it is when clicking the other links. I only want to change direction for "main menu link".

http://jsfiddle.net/L7v0w96s/10/

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('a.panel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.animate({
                left: $this.innerWidth()
            }, 500, function() {
                $this.removeClass('active')
            });
        });

        $target.css({
            left: -($target.innerWidth())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500).addClass('active');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Go to nearer there but i miss something. Hope give way to move forward. 
http://jsfiddle.net/L7v0w96s/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7v0w96s/24/)

Key changes:

HTML

```
<a href="#target0" class="panel main">
```

CSS

```
div.panel {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* prevents the boxes from being too big because of padding */
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Javascript - calculate the different start and end positions for the animation, depending on the link clicked.

```
isMain = $(this).is(".main"),
myStart = isMain ? 0 : $target.outerWidth() * -1,
myEnd = isMain ? $target.outerWidth() * -1: 0
otherEnd = isMain ? 
   $other.filter(".active").outerWidth() * -1 : 
   $other.filter(".active").outerWidth();
```

Use the calculated values in the animation logic

```
if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
    $other.each(function(index, self) {
       var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({
            left: otherEnd
        }, 500, function() {
            $this.removeClass('active')
        });
   });

   $target.css({
       left: myStart
   }).animate({
       left: 0
   }, 500).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: ok,that works! but now it looks like the gray panel is under the colored panel is is only being revealed. As opposed to the gray panel actually sliding in. It might be that the time between slides need to change. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, that definitely is it. There needs to be a delay in there. The same delay as the other slides.

Comment: I just tried to add the delay, but really don't know how. And I'm not even sure that is the problem. It just doesn't look right to me.  "This is the Target Menu
Target 1
Target 2
Target 3" needs to have the correct space between the text and the edge of the side of the panel sliding out.

Comment: I'm about done with my adjustments, i'll post an update in a minute.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to post another question or if you are going to post. No rush, just wondering.

Comment: Ok, new fiddle is up.

Comment: Thank you for doing that. It still looks a little funky, but I'm going to try and tweak it the best I can.